# How to change design of suggestions in Monaco Editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, monaco-editor

I try to change design and inject some html tag in monaco editor suggestions.

for example

```
const suggestions = 
      {
        label: 'CPU',
        detail: 'cpu',
        unit: 'byte',
        insertText: 'cpu === ${1:value}',
        insertTextRules: monaco.languages.CompletionItemInsertTextRule.InsertAsSnippet,
      },

//register suggestions by registerCompletionItemProvider


const suggestionRenderer = (suggestion) => {
  const {label, unit, detail} = suggestion;
  return <div>{label}<span class="info">{unit}</span>{detail}</div>
}

// adding suggestionRender to monaco
```

Is there any renderer method for suggestions in monaco editor?